# Can I delete a file called 'UPDATE' in the dload folder, or will this delete the operating system?

Tags: updates, file-system, huawei-u8860

I recently received low space warnings on my Huawei Honor so I connected my phone to the Mac and observed the files:

[image: Can this be deleted?]

As you can see, perhaps 75% is taken up by a file called 'UPDATE' in the dload folder.  Can I delete this?  Is this an install file or is it the operating system?!

Obviously I could answer my own question by deleting it but I don't want to delete the operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't delete the OS.  Looks to just be a small update file.

Comment: And even if it would be large: It's just a download. Deleting this file will, humm, ah, eh, delete this file, not more :)

Comment: Thanks @Kris Gruttemeyer, I deleted it and now have loads of space on my phone.  Operating system intact!

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, I deleted it and now have loads of space on my phone.  Operating system intact!